# How to set the title of navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, title

The structure of my storyboard is below

a--b--c,d,e

a is a navigation controller ,
b is a tabbar controller,
c,d,e are three tab views.

at each of the tab bar view ,how to set the navigation bar title?
I tried the self.navigationItem.title=@"...",but it doesn't work.

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title go for this.

Comment: Are you intending to push and pop through the navigation controller from the three tabs? i.e. C goes to C1, C2, C3 and then back... D goes to D1, etc...

Comment: Yes,I put the self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title in viewdidAppear, i automatically change the title.it's what i want.